# How To Detect An Email Address Is Real

Tags: java, email

## IMPORTANT

> I have been blocked by hotmail services. There is a control mechanism
> called spamhaus which kicked me out. I'm stuck right now.

I am trying to detect an email address is valid and if its valid then check if this email address potentially used (I know that its not certain). For example, lets assume that there is a website with domain `myimaginarydomain.com`. If I run code below, I guess it won't fail because domain address is valid. But nobody can take an email address with that domain.

Is there any way to find out that email address is valid? (In this case its invalid)

- I don't want to send confirmation email
- Sending ping may be useful?

```java
    public class Application {
        private static EmailValidator validator = EmailValidator.getInstance();
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            while (true) {
                Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
                String email = scn.nextLine();
                boolean isValid = validateEmail(email);
                System.out.println("Syntax is : " + isValid);
    
                if (isValid) {
                    String domain = email.split("@")[1];
                    try {
                        int test = doLookup(domain);
                        System.out.println(domain + " has " + test + " mail servers");
                    } catch (NamingException e) {
                        System.out.println(domain + " has 0 mail servers");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private static boolean validateEmail(String email) {
            return validator.isValid(email);
        }
    
        static int doLookup(String hostName) throws NamingException {
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
                    "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
            DirContext ictx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            Attributes attrs =
                    ictx.getAttributes(hostName, new String[]{"MX"});
            Attribute attr = attrs.get("MX");
            if (attr == null) return (0);
            return (attr.size());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no failsafe way to do this in all cases, but, assuming the server uses SMTP then https://www.labnol.org/software/verify-email-address/18220/ gives quite a good tutorial on one method that may work.

The method used in the tutorial relies on OS tools, so you will need to ensure they exist before using them. a `ProcessBuilder` may help. Alternatively, you can open a socket directly in code and avoid using OS-dependent tools.

Essentially, you find out what the mail servers are (using nslookup), then telnet to one of the mail servers and start writing an email:

> 3a: Connect to the mail server:
>
> `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`
>
> 3b: Say hello to the other server
>
> `HELO`
>
> 3c: Identify yourself with some fictitious email address
>
> `mail from:<labnol@labnol.org>`
>
> 3d: Type the recipient’s email address that you are trying to verify:
>
> `rcpt to:<billgates@gmail.com>`
>
> The server response for `rcpt to` command will give you an idea whether an email address is valid or not. You’ll get an “OK” if the address exists else a 550 error

Comment: Telnet is very little more than a TCP connection with some encoding of special characters that doesn't apply in this case. You could just use a socket and avoid introducing dependencies on system tools and a particular operating system.

Comment: Yep, I can use these without os dependent way. Thanks a lot

Comment: The answer also assumes that the server is smtp

Comment: @jr593 are there any other standards by which an email can be *delivered* to a destination domain? AFAIK that step is only handled by SMTP and its TLS-secured variant, ESMTP.

Comment: When I try to send ehlo / helo message to gmail servers, it returns an error 501 called not allowed, closing connection. How can I add any certificate or needed information into request? Thanks

Comment: Found solution. I used HELO + ip and everything worked. Thanks

Comment: A big problem has occured. When I try to validate some emails, I've got blocked by hotmail. I can recognize that my IP has been blocked. How to add AUTH LOGIN to my SMTP commands? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There really is no sensible way except trying to send a notification with a token to the address and ask the other party to confirm it, usually by visiting a web-page:

- the recipients MX may be unavailable at the moment but come back online later, so you cannot rely on a lookup in real time;
- just because the MX accepts the email doesn't mean that the address is valid, the message could bounce later down the pipe (think UUCP);
- if this is some kind of registration service, you need to provide some confirmation step anyway as otherwise it'd become too easy to subscribe random strangers on the internet that do not want your service.